# Converting PHP cURL to C# Request

Tags: c#, php, .net, curl

I have the following code in PHP which returns an XML file and works great.  My problem is that I need to implement the same function using C#.  As I am fairly new to .NET, can someone point me in the right direction?

```
$url = "http://myDestinationDomain.com";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true);
$temp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try out this code. It might have some errors though you should be able to work out on it

I've got it from this link
http://forums.asp.net/t/1178426.aspx/1

```
 public static XmlDocument getXMLDocumentFromXMLTemplate(string inURL)
        {
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;     //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebRequest class.
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;   //Declare an HTTP-specific implementation of the WebResponse class
            XmlDocument myXMLDocument = null;           //Declare XMLResponse document
            XmlTextReader myXMLReader = null;           //Declare XMLReader

            try
            {
                //Create Request
                myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(inURL);
                myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
                myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";

                //Get Response
                myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

                //Now load the XML Document
                myXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();

                //Load response stream into XMLReader
                myXMLReader = new XmlTextReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
                myXMLDocument.Load(myXMLReader);
            }
            catch (Exception myException)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error Occurred in AuditAdapter.getXMLDocumentFromXMLTemplate()", myException);
            }
            finally
            {
                myHttpWebRequest = null;
                myHttpWebResponse = null;
                myXMLReader = null;
            }
            return myXMLDocument;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Murtuza.  I figured it out with your help.